# $posts jquery submits my form

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function claim()
    {
        var c = confirm('You sure?');

        if(c)
        {
            var password=prompt("Please mention pw","");
            if (password!=null && password!="")
              {
                    $.post("/claim/<?php echo $refnr; ?>", { partner_pwd: password },
                       function(data) { 
                            alert(data);
                            if(data == '1')
                            {
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                return false;
                            }
                       });
              }else{
                return false;
              }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

When testing I get to the Please mention pw, after i entered and press OK it submits my form, instead of making the $.post and only submit my form if data == '1' (return true)

claim() is called at my submit button;

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return claim()"; value="Submit" />
```

I tried alert debugging and it was true like i thought it automatically submits when it reads the $.post(), I only wish it to submit (by returning true) if the data is 1.

Comment: Please check that after your `$.post` request you do not return `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return true` and `return false` inside of your `$.post` request do nothing but return out of that callback. It does not prevent the form from submitting. Instead, try preventing the submit completely and then triggering it if you want the submit to happen.

```
function claim() {
    var c = confirm('You sure?');

    if (!c) {
        return false;
    }

    var password = prompt("Please mention pw", "");
    if (password != null && password != "") {
        $.post("/claim/<?php echo $refnr; ?>", {
            partner_pwd: password
        }, function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data == '1') {
                $("#myform").submit();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}​
```

Note how we *always* `return false` out of that function regardless of the validity. If it is valid, we trigger the form's submit event directly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you put a form in a website, it's goal is to submit the form.

http://api.jquery.com/submit/ (scroll down to the very last example starting with `Example: If you'd like to prevent forms from being submitted unless a flag variable is set, try:`)

As stated in the link above, you should change form's action instead of some page and do something like `action="javascript:claim()"`. I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick method on the submit it's not working because the form will be submitted eitherway.

You should for example set a listener on the `onsubmit();` event on the form 
or another solution is on the  put the `onsubmit` attribute with your javascript function in it and submit the form from your javascript with the `$('#form').submit();` function.